# Very strange error caused by html whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have encountered a very strange bug in Firefox.

I have a javascript function in an external file that works perfectly on regular complexity websites. However I have been putting together a few demonstration examples and come across something odd.

With html formatted like this (in an editor):

```
<div><p>Q: Where's the rabbit?</p><p class="faq_answer">A: I don't know, honest</p></div>
```

The Javascript works as expected.

However when like this:

```
<div>
<p>Q: Where's the rabbit?</p>
<p class="faq_answer">A: I don't know, honest</p>
</div>
```

It fails at this line:

```
elementsList[i].parentNode.firstChild.appendChild(finalRender.cloneNode(true));
```

Why on Earth would formatting of html cause anything at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug. The DOM has not only element nodes, but also [**text nodes** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) (among others). In this example:

```
<div>
<p>Q: Where's the rabbit?</p>
```

you have at least two text nodes:

- One between the `<div>` and the `<p>`,  containing a *line-break*.
- One text node inside the `<p>` element node, containing the text `Where's the rabbit?`.

Thus, if `elementsList[i].parentNode` refers to the `<div>` element,

```
elementsList[i].parentNode.firstChild
```

will refer to the first text node.

If you want to get the first *element node*, use

```
elementsList[i].parentNode.children[0]
```

---

**Update:** You mentioned Firefox 3.0, and indeed, [the `children` property is not supported in this version](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71).

Afaik the only solution to this is to loop over the children (or traversing them) and test whether it is a text node or not:

```
var firstChild = elementsList[i].parentNode.firstChild;

// a somehow shorthand loop
while(firstChild.nodeType !== 1 && (firstChild = firstChild.nextSibling));

if(firstChild) {
    // exists and found
}
```

You might want to put this in an extra function:

```
function getFirstElementChild(element) {
    var firstChild = null;
    if(element.children) {
        firstChild = element.children[0] || null;
    }
    else {
      firstChild = element.firstChild;
      while(firstChild.nodeType !== 1 && (firstChild = firstChild.nextSibling));
    }
    return firstChild;
}
```

You can (and should) also consider using a library that abstracts from all that, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

It depends on what your code is actually doing, but if you run this method for every node, it would be something like:

```
$('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true));
```

(assuming the `p` element always comes before the `.faq_answer` element)

This is the whole code, you wouldn't have to loop over the elements anymore.

Comment: That hasn't worked. The parser simply gives up at this point like there is a syntex error. (like it was before)

Comment: @YsoL8: What is the error, where is the JS code? What is `elementsList[i]`? What does `elementsList[i].parentNode` refer to? I just made assumptions based on the little information you have given. It's enough to explain *why* it does not work, but give a working solution, we need more information.

Comment: elementsList[i] is an element of the class faq_answer in this case. Therefore it's parent is the div and the div's first child is the unclassed p tag.

Comment: @YsoL8: Then `children[0]` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/dWmqN/ (works in Chrome and FF5).

Comment: OK this --might-- be a version problem as the company computer here is on FF 3.0.3 and neither the fiddle or my adjusted code appear to work.

Comment: @YsoL8: Yes it is: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71 Give me a second to update my answer.

Comment: Do you know the jquery function? (Just begining to migrate over to it, to avoid presicely these kinds of problems)

Comment: @YsoL8: Well it depends on what your code is actually doing, but if you run this method for every node, it would something like: `$('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true))` (assuming the `p` element comes always before the `.faq_answer` element).

Comment: OK. Your Jquery works for me. +1 for help in general and another (if I can) for pointing out I don't need looping. =>

Comment: @Felix Kling: I really haven't heard about the `Text Nodes` before. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a text node between `<div>` and `<p>`.

As usual, the assumption of a browser bug is incorrect: this is, instead, a programmer bug!

Comment: Not helpful. And disdainful.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't one achieve it by using [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) instead?