# Can you make a scrollable div maintain the size of the scrollback using FIFO

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a div container with the following css

```
#game-container {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
border: thick solid #808080;
height: 400px;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: auto;}
```

I also use this function to keep the scrollbar at the bottom of the container.

```
function scrollToBottom(container) {
        var messages = $(container);
        messages.scrollTop(messages[0].scrollHeight);
    }
```

It works as expected and as data is appended to the container it scrolls up.  What i want to do is limit the amount of scrollback the container holds using a first in first out method of maintaining the contents of the container.  So if the container is holding 20 lines or pixels or whatever measurement is used in the scrollback it will toss out the first contents and maintain its size as new content is appended, tossing out the first content as it grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to **remove the first element child(ren)** in the container until the minimum height has been attained.

The best moment to do that could be immediately after you've inserted new content to the bottom of the container.

Regarding removing child elements, you may refer to the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14294518/278405) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6572408/278405).